# how to center a content into a td element

Tags: css

I have this code

```
<td  colspan="2" rowspan="5" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" >
```

and the result is this:

[image]

I hovered the area for you.

#### what I need

is making the area `Total Call Status` in the center of the td.

help please

Comment: Post a complete code example please, including your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `text-align: center`.

Comment: +1 to you , I hope i can accept more than one answer but the other guy answered first

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli you can't but sort by oldest.

Comment: oh yes , you the one first. thanks. i will accept ur answer after 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
<td  colspan="2" rowspan="5" align="center" >
```

Or

```
<td  colspan="2" rowspan="5" style="text-align:center;" >
```

Both will work.

Comment: +1 to you , sorry friend, it seems there is another guy answered first, i hope i can accept more than answer

Comment: Keep in mind: This will also center any text you put inside the table data tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td colspan="2" rowspan="5" ><div style="margin: 0 auto;">Content goes here...</div></td>
```

This method will not center any text you put inside your `<td>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/edshK/)

It is rather easy with `margin: 0 auto;` I wouldn't use `text-align:center`, unless you want everything in it centered including text. I'd rather have the elements center and still have the option to have my text left, center, right, or justified.  Open options are great